# How to reconcile SRP and "Don't Create Verb Classes"

Tags: oop, software-design

Having recently taken a deeper dive into best practices concerning object-oriented design, I have reached an impasse. If I follow SRP, I end up with MessageSender. But "Don't Create Verb Classes" tells me I should have Message#send, instead, violating the single responsibility of the Message class in the case that #send is highly involved.

How can each of my classes adhere to the single responsibility principle (SRP), but also have no verb in its title (http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontCreateVerbClasses)?

Answer (score 0):

If the send functionality might become complex, it would make sense to have a MessageSender that is solely responsible for this. A MessageManager could contain an instance of MessageSender, and could be used as such:

`$messageManager->send();`

Whereby:

```
public function send(){
    $this->messageSender->send();
}
```

Using this structure, you could create new MessageSenders derived from the base class, and interchange then by using a setter to set it on the MessageManager. That may be unlikey for your needs, but it highlights what is possible

Comment: Yes, that is a design that functions, but it still makes use of a verb class (the **`send`** in `MessageSender`).